# Can not upload file to provided Azure containers

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint

I try upload file to provided Azure containers which it is taken from ProvisionMigrationContainers() method, however it was not successful.

I am using below C# code:

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(urlSring);
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in passWord) securePassword.AppendChar(c);

        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
        ClientResult<ProvisionedMigrationContainersInfo> containerInfo = clientContext.Site.ProvisionMigrationContainers();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        var containerInfoList = containerInfo.Value;
        var dataContainerUri = containerInfoList.DataContainerUri;
        var metadataContainerUri = containerInfoList.MetadataContainerUri;

        CloudBlobContainer dataContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(dataContainerUri));
        CloudBlobContainer manifestContainer = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(metadataContainerUri));

        //Upload data to container start
        var testfiles = new[]
        {
            new SourceFile
            {
                Filename = "test.txt",
                LastModified = DateTime.Now,
                Contents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hi, this is a test text-file"),
                Title = "Title of file 1"
            },
            new SourceFile
            {
                Filename = "test2.txt",
                LastModified = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                Contents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Tesfile2"),
                Title = "Second title"
            }
        };

        foreach (var testfile in testfiles)
        {
            var blobReference = dataContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(testfile.Filename);
            blobReference.UploadFromByteArray(testfile.Contents, 0, testfile.Contents.Length);
        }
```

When i get list blob from provided Azure containers with below code, it returns null.

```
        var blobList = dataContainer.ListBlobs();
        var fileList = blobList.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Would you please tell me the reason?

Thanks in advance

RonLee.

Comment: This problem is a bit complicated, and no suitable solution has been found yet. You can raise a support ticket on the portal.

Comment: Dear Jason, 
Can you  show me where I can raise the issue?

Comment: You can see the article to [create an azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).